# Asp.net callback

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to learn how to create a more real time callback from one client to another within asp.net. I did a little googleing and found asp.net callbacks with script manager within asp.net. What is the best pattern and practice for creating an on demand website between mutiple clients? Is the scriptmanager and detecting the current user that is signed it best practice?(

Comment: There is any live example of what you are talking about? Sorry, I have no idea what you mean

Comment: @Brandon - I Agree with Claudio... what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: An "on demand website between multiple clients"?  Technically that describe the class of sites known as "web applications".  I think we'll need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's AJAX functionality and ASP.Net WebServices to pass JSON data back and forth. Easy. If that's what you're talking about... I don't quite get it.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. My end result is posting a note on a page then that note will be displayed to any users that on currently on the same page.

I am really trying to figure out how to do a global callback to all users and if it is best... filter the users name or userid based on the role I already have

Comment: If it were me, I would use jQuery's AJAX and .Net web services as I said before. It's perfect for what you want to do (as I understand). You can post the note with AJAX, as well as put a timer on the page that looks for updates to display to other users on the same page.